# TornadoFX:proper way to bind model

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I was taking a look at this :
[tornadofx](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part1/11.%20Editing%20Models%20and%20Validation.html)

and tried to expand on it with database connection and little more options, (not all of them make sense, but its just playing in a sandbox).

Even though table can be directly edited and the data will persist in database, i did try to do edit through text fields too. actual table editing would happen through different view and not table itself, as i said its just example.
Database used is Jetbrains Exposed.

```
    object Categories : IntIdTable() {
    val name = varchar("name", 64).uniqueIndex()
    val description = varchar("description", 128)
}

class Category(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Category>(Categories)

    var name by Categories.name
    var description by Categories.description

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Category(name=\"$name\", description=\"$description\")"
    }
}
```

now controller looks something like this, functions are just rudimentary and picked as an example.

```
typealias ModelToDirtyState = Map.Entry<CategoryModel, TableColumnDirtyState<CategoryModel>>

class CategoryModel() : ItemViewModel<Category>() {
    val name: SimpleStringProperty = bind(Category::name)
    val description: SimpleStringProperty = bind(Category::description)
}


class DBController : Controller() {

    val categories: ObservableList<CategoryModel> by lazy {

        transaction {
            SchemaUtils.create(Categories)
            Category.all().map {
                CategoryModel().apply {
                    item = it
                }
            }.observable()
        }
    }

    init {
        Database.connect(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
            user = "test", password = "test"
        )

        TransactionManager.manager.defaultIsolationLevel = Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE
    }

    fun deleteCategory(model: CategoryModel) {
        runAsync {
            transaction {
                model.item.delete()
            }

        }
        categories.remove(model)
    }

    fun updateCategory(model: CategoryModel) {
        transaction {
            Categories.update {
                model.commit()
            }


        }

    }



 fun commitDirty(modelDirtyMappings: Sequence<ModelToDirtyState>) {
        transaction {
            modelDirtyMappings.filter { it.value.isDirty }.forEach {
                it.key.commit()
                println(it.key)// commit value to database
                it.value.commit()   // clear dirty state
            }
        }
    }
```

Just to quickly comment on controller, delete method works as "intended" however the update one does not, it does not work in sense that after using delete item is remove both from database and tableview(underlying list) itself, and when i do update its not, now i know the reason, i call remove manually on both database and list, now for update perhaps i could do change listener, or maybe tornadofx can do this for me, i just cant set it up to do it. Following code will make things clearer i think.

```
class CategoryEditor : View("Categories") {
    val categoryModel: CategoryModel by inject()
    val dbController: DBController by inject()
    var categoryTable: TableViewEditModel<CategoryModel> by singleAssign()
    var categories: ObservableList<CategoryModel> by singleAssign()


    override val root = borderpane {
        categories = dbController.categories

        center = vbox {
            buttonbar {
                button("Commit") {
                    action {
                        dbController.commitDirty(categoryTable.items.asSequence())
                    }
                }
                button("Roll;back") {
                    action {
                        categoryTable.rollback()
                    }
                }

//                This model only works when i use categorytable.tableview.selected item, if i use categoryModel, list gets updated but not the view itself
//                Question #1 how to use just categoryModel variable without need to use categorytable.tableview.selecteditem
                button("Delete ") {
                    action {
                        val model = categoryTable.tableView.selectedItem
                        when (model) {
                            null -> return@action
                            else -> dbController.deleteCategory(model)
                        }
                    }
                }

                //And here no matter what i did i could not make the view update 
                button("Update") {
                    action {

                        when (categoryModel) {
                            null -> return@action
                            else -> dbController.updateCategory(categoryModel)


                        }
                        categoryTable.tableView.refresh()

                    }
                }
            }
            tableview<CategoryModel> {
                categoryTable = editModel
                items = categories

                enableCellEditing()
                enableDirtyTracking()
                onUserSelect() {
                   //open a dialog
                }

                //DOES WORK
                categoryModel.rebindOnChange(this) { selectedItem ->
                    item = selectedItem?.item ?: CategoryModel().item

                }
//                Question #2. why bindSelected does not work, and i have to do it like above 
                //DOES NOT WORK
 //               bindSelected(categoryModel)
//
                column("Name", CategoryModel::name).makeEditable()
                column("Description", CategoryModel::description).makeEditable()
            }
        }
        right = form {

            fieldset {
                field("Name") {
                    textfield(categoryModel.name)
                }
            }
            fieldset {
                field("Description") {
                    textfield(categoryModel.description)
                }
            }
            button("ADD CATEGORY") {
                action {
                    dbController.addCategory(categoryModel.name.value, categoryModel.description.value)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for huge amount of code, also in last code snipped i left questions in form of comments where i fail to achive desired results.
 I am sure i am not properly binding code, i just dont see why, also i sometimes use one variable to update data, my declared one "categoryModel" and sometimes i use tableview.selecteditem, it just seems hacky and i cant seem to grasp way.

Thank you!

Comment: I had similar issues with TornadoFX. The lowercase discriptions of "UIElements" are methods wich return the Object and apply the given fields and assignments, But because of mysterious reasons some objects produces within the scope of the method, won't be applied/assigned. Have you tried using a Object instead of the TornadoFX functionality? like `var tableView:Tableview = Tableview()` and then `tableView.apply{ //all your assigments}`  ? Create a function that returns the initiated Tableview  to your VBox, instead of doing this within the "apply method" of the Vbox

Comment: I have problems as well but in the opposite; bindSelected achieves what I want whereas rebindOnChange fails. In my situation, the object I bind to the model has a list which refuses to perform rollback whenever I use rebindOnChange whereas with bindSelected it works. All in all, it seems like these two do different work under the hood...